# Cellular or acyclic inequalities for homotopy fibers of suspension maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is it true that (modulo connectivity hypotheses perhaps)
$$
\mathrm{Fib}(f) < \mathrm{Fib}(g)
$$
implies
$$
\mathrm{Fib}(\Sigma f) < \mathrm{Fib}(\Sigma g)?
$$

A class $\mathcal{C}$ of pointed spaces is **strongly closed** if it is closed under weak equivalence, pointed homotopy colimit, and extension by fibrations. We write $X<Y$ if every strongly closed class containing $X$ also contains $Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure what $<$ means, but maybe not. What about cases where $\Sigma f$ is nullhomotopic?

Comment: Isn't there a work by Dror-Farjoun or Chacolski somewhat related to this?

Comment: Yes, those are among the biggest names in this subject. I haven't found this question addressed in the literature, though.